# VS test-detection with indirect Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk-reference?

Tags: c#, nuget

We would like a common test-tools-package (used by all test-projects) to also gather all references to 3rd-party test-stuff. However visual studio's test-runner require a direct `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk`-reference to enable test-detection.

[A comment in vstest](https://github.com/microsoft/vstest/issues/515#issuecomment-347825351) says

> Although IMO if you want to keep the dependency on nugets common through your projects, the correct way to do so would be via keeping a common targets, & props file which will bring in those dependencies for all your projects.

So, it's possible to 'redirect' to packages that usually require direct reference by [setting properties in the .csproj-file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70791168/470022)...? After some searching I still haven't found exactly how. Hopefully coverlet's PrivateAssets and IncludeAssets could be DRY'ed the same way.

Any help much appreciated, but to end in a focused question:
*How can package-references that usually need to be direct (for test-detection) be gathered in a common test-tools-package?*